# __TCC_CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION + 163

Tags: c++, macos, qt

So, I developed an app in Qt. It works just fine on my MacOs virtual machine. So I deployed it, I codesigned it. But I get an error, when I'm trying to launch on another Mac device. Funnny thing is if I launch it using `sudo`, like `sudo App.app/Contents/MacOS/App` it works. The error text is

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20364792 abort_with_payload + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203661d9 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2036620b abort_with_payload + 9
3   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff24bd61b4 __TCC_CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION + 163
4   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff24bd69e6 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.128 + 498
5   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff24bd460a __tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 573
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff200bcab8 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff200bca40 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 69
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201cc831 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201e5010 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 375
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201dc564 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1390
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203744e1 _pthread_wqthread + 386
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20373467 start_wqthread + 15
```

And I have really hard time trying to understand what's the reason for such behaviour. I read some information about related problems, and it seem like it's missing some kind of permission. But I can't understand what excatly the permission should be. Can anyone explain what should I do?

Comment: This usually means your application is accessing some data that requires a privacy policy or data usage policy and your application doesn't have the appropriate policy attached. For example, do you access the photo library and not have a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription message property?

Comment: No, I don't. But I use bluetooth and camera. And I already added NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription, NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription. I also added NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription to my info.plist since I'm using it to write some data. But it didn't work.